# Using concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor when we do not have access to the __main__ module

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I am running a large python project with multiple files.
I want to use a concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor to execute a compute bound piece of code.

The project is organized as :
main.py -> execute.py -> helper.py

I run main.py, which calls a function in execute.py, which further calls a function (func()) in helper.py
I want to speed-up a code block func() which is currently the bottleneck.

I can use ThreadPoolExecutor to speed the code up. However, because of python GIL, and also since the code block to be optimized is compute heavy, I wish to use ProcessPoolExecutor in hopes of gaining more speedup.

Now, here is the problem:
Seems like unlike a ThreadPoolExecutor, a ProcessPoolExecutor needs access to the '**main**' module. {refer to the 1st point in : [https://superfastpython.com/processpoolexecutor-common-errors/}](https://superfastpython.com/processpoolexecutor-common-errors/%7D).

Hence, when I use a ProcessPoolExecutor inside func(), I get an error saying "concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending"

Is there any way I can leverage multiprocessing here (and create processpool instead of threadpool)?
I cannot change the project structure (the way files are organized in the project).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Instead of describing what your code does,  please include your actual code and the full traceback error.

Comment: @ewokx sorry but it is not possible for me to include the actual code. However, I believe that I have described the problem well enough for people to be able to follow. Request you to please have a look and let me know in case you need any more information. Thanks

Comment: It's not a question of having *access* to `__main__` . Any code at global scope in the initial script that is being executed that ultimately results in creating a child process must be within an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.